# Next-auth keep redirecting to '/api/auth/error' instead of showing error on my login page

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I set:

```
  pages: {
    signIn: "/admin/login",
    error: "/admin/login",
  },
```

but after I enter wrong credentials, next-auth redirect me on '/api/auth/error' instead showing error on my 'admin/login' page.

EDIT:

Also, in terminal I get this error:

```
 error TypeError: Cannot convert argument to a ByteString because the character at index 45 has a value of 273 which is greater than 255.
at webidl.converters.ByteString (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1578:17)
at Headers.set (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1877:35)
at toResponse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/utils.js:52:40)
at NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:65:44)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:83:24)
at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:249:37)
```

Comment: Sometimes it's redirect to the /api/auth/error i think its a bug

Comment: What can I do with this, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have this folder structure: `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

You can also follow this [guide](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app)